# Confusion about the derivative in CTC

Tags: neural-networks, natural-language, recurrent-neural-network, speech-recognition

I was going through the original [CTC paper by Graves et al](https://www.cs.toronto.edu/%7Egraves/icml_2006.pdf), I am still not getting how after taking the derivative of equation 14 we get equation 15 as shown below[image]

I understand the part that we are considering only those paths that involve the label we are taking the gradient of.

I just don't get how we get equation 15 after differentiating 14. Any help or hints will be appreciated.

Blockquote

Comment: Can you explain CTC?